# How to control website using mobile app

Tags: javascript, php, websocket, socket.io, mobile-application

I have edited my question to make more meaningful and easy to understand.

How can I make a mobile app which can control my website, Website is already built and working written in php-mysql, jQuery etc.

Websites have alot of links and most of the pages are stand alone which have forms to show some output (Data in tabular format and some charts).

I want my mobile app to work like remote control. If i select a link in my mobile app then it should sync with desktop monitor the page which is  already open and user is logged in.

Since pages are too big to fit in mobile so i want to have hyperlinks and form (check box, radio button, dropdown etc) for each page in mobile so that i can select and show output in big screen.

Here is a example but not complete - https://tz-smartphone-remote-control.herokuapp.com/#/3/1

If you open this in mobile you can sync the same page with big screen.

Using this - http://tutorialzine.com/2015/02/smartphone-remote-control-for-presentations/ i can make it working but i don't want to write everything (website) again. 
All i want is some simple way to add something in website and create mobile app which can navigate pages.

Thanks

Comment: Don't you think it is *TOO BROAD* ?

Comment: I know this is complicated and thats why I am here to discuss with you guys and I know this is possible. Some people already made this using websocket.

Comment: firebase, pubnub, pusher, meteor, socket.io, etc. i've said too much...

Comment: Please edit your question and be more specific. i.e. What do you mean by "control" - shut the server down? edit content? push chat messages or news reports? ... What code did you try? What did you look into? ... If your question is too broad (and it definitely is) it will be ignored by the community, get down voted and be flagged for removal. Please help us help you.

Comment: @Myst - I have edited my question.